# UNC path for Flash Trusted Locations

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a SWF file located on the local network. The SWF plays some FLV video clips in the same directory and also has a hyperlink at the end that is created with getURL(). T

I am currently getting “Adobe Flash Player has stopped a potentially unsafe operation.”

Adding the path to Trusted Location in Flash’s setting fixes the problem. However, I have to map the network location to a letter drive. I have well over 100 PC's that can access this SWF, so I'm trying to avoid mapping a letter drive. Is there a way to add a UNC path to the Trusted Locations, or another fix that I haven’t found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit Trusted location setup in your local network with 100+ computers, by providing your swf from the local web server (http://myLocalNetwork.com/myHandmadeSwf/)

Also another option for you, wrap your swf as AIR application. It isn't hard, but your 100+ computers should have AIR Runtime.